# Print CrystalReportViewer document using C#

Tags: c#, printing, crystal-reports

I want to print the report displayed in CrystalReportViewer. I used this code to preview the report in CrystalReportViewer:

```
private void previewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql1 = "SELECT * FROM SousCategorie WHERE Stock > 0";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);
    SqlDataAdapter dscmd1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
    dscmd1.Fill(ds1, "SousCategorie");
    CrystalReport5 objRpt2 = new CrystalReport5();
    objRpt2.SetDataSource(ds1);
    crystalReportViewer5.ReportSource = objRpt2;
    crystalReportViewer5.Refresh();
}
```

And I used this code to print the report previewed in CrystalReportViewer:

```
private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CrystalReport5 objRpt4 = new CrystalReport5();
    objRpt4.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = PaperOrientation.Portrait;
    objRpt4.PrintOptions.PaperSize = PaperSize.PaperA4;
    objRpt4.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
}
```

But I got a blank report printed. How to print the report like the print button existing in CrystalReportViewer tool bar?

Comment: Have you tried `crystalReportViewer5.PrintReport`?

Comment: Thank you very much this solved my problem